# Failed to generate manifest from function source: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'secret') react js node js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I try to replace:

```
const stripe =const stripe=require("stripe")('sk_test_51KMbN...');
```

to

```
const stripe = require("stripe")(functions.config().stripe.secret);
```

but when I run firebase emulators, I Run into an error:

Error: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'secret')

I already set it as below:

```
firebase functions:config:set stripe.secret=< SECRET KEY>
```

and I can see it by runing:

```
firebase functions:config:get
```

[image]

My code in functions/index.js is

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const express=require("express");
const cors=require("cors");
require('dotenv').config({ path: './.env' });
//API
const stripe = require("stripe")(functions.config().stripe.secret);

//App config
const app=express();
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
var serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey.json");
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});
//middlewares
app.use(cors({origin: true}));
app.use(express.json());
async function createCheckoutSession(req, res) {
  
  const domainUrl = process.env.WEB_APP_URL;
  const { line_items, customer_email } = req.body;
  if (!line_items || !customer_email) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: 'missing required session parameters' });
  }
  let session; 
  try {
    session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
      payment_method_types: ['card'],
      mode: 'payment',
      line_items,
      customer_email,
      success_url: `${domainUrl}/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
      cancel_url: `${domainUrl}/canceled`,
      shipping_address_collection: { allowed_countries: ['GB', 'US'] }
    }); 
    res.status(200).json({ sessionId: session.id, });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(400).json({ error: 'an error occured, unable to create session'});
  }}
app.get('/',(req, res)=>res.send('Hello World!'));
app.post('/create-checkout-session', createCheckoutSession);
exports.api=functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

the code has no problem when I define:

```
 const stripe =const stripe=require("stripe")('sk_test_51KMbNcJ....');
```

I do not know why it cannot read properties of undefined "functions.config().stripe.secret"

Comment: `functions.config().stripe.secret` should work if you're setting it with `firebase functions:config:set stripe.secret="sk_..."`.  Perhaps something else is using that name?  Maybe try `.stripedebug.secret` instead?  Or if you log the value of `functions.config().stripe` what do you get?

Comment: Hi Justin, I did run firebase functions:config:set stripe.secret=sk......, and log functions.config().stripe show {"secret":"sk_..."}, run firebase functions:config:get also show  {"secret":"sk_..."}, but I still get the same error "Error: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'secret')" when run firebase emulators, I even run firebase functions:config:get > .runtimeconfig.json as suggested in github forum, still get the same error. I have no clue what is wrong'

Comment: To clarify, in your code, if you add `console.log(functions.config().stripe);` just before the `const stripe = require("stripe")(functions.config().stripe.secret);` line you see the API key as expected, but you still get the same error?

Comment: Yes, I use functions.logger.info("functions config log ",functions.config().stripe) after const stripe = require("stripe")(functions.config().stripe.secret);, but i think it does not mater whether it is before or after since I use:  firebase functions:config:set stripe.secret="sk_..." to set it and It shows the secret key l after I run firebase functions:config:get. It seems that the secret has been defined/set, but I don't know it still show the error when i run firebase emulators:start. I edited the post by adding the functions.config().stripe info

Comment: Sorry, I think there's a misunderstanding.  I'm saying in your actual code (**not** using the `firebase` tool), if you add `console.log(functions.config().stripe);` what do you see in the log?

Comment: as Function emulator stop and given the above-mentioned error, it did not show the console.log(functions.config().stripe) result. but the function emulator log in the terminal show "Found .runtimeconfig.json but the JSON format is invalid." and "It looks like you're trying to access functions.config().stripe but there is no value there. You can learn more about setting up config here https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator", when I go to the link about setting up config, the only step I am not sure is To set up admin credentials for emulated functions step 4.Set your Google..

Comment: If you open `.runtimeconfig.json` does it look unusual in any way?  Can you rename it to something `.runtimeconfig.json.bad` and then have `firebase` regenerate it?

Answer (score 7):

If, like me, you got this error while trying to run your functions locally then it's because functions.config() is only available within the Cloud Functions runtime.

If you are trying to test your functions before you deploy, here is the link to the documentation on how to do so: run functions locally. Specifically, this part is of interest:

If you're using custom functions configuration variables, run the following command in the functions directory of your project before running firebase serve.

```
firebase functions:config:get > .runtimeconfig.json
```

However, if you're using Windows PowerShell, replace the above command with:

```
firebase functions:config:get | ac .runtimeconfig.json
```

Comment: Hey, double check your link to the documentation.